# Why shtml.exe comes in url

Tags: html, shtml

I have found shtml.exe in my localhost URL.Url is : localhost/germain/_vti_bin/shtml.exe/reservations.htm.

When i enterd this url the page shows a 403 error.

[image]

But in the case of live site it works fine.Look this link : http://www.germainesluau.com/_vti_bin/shtml.exe/reservations.htm

is there any settings have to change in htaccess?

Please give me an advise?

Comment: May I guess, that you a developing your site on Linux, but the final Server is running Windows?

Comment: @Nippey currently i am working on linux and testing in localhost

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The live server has FrontPage extensions installed.

```
# curl -I http://www.germainesluau.com/_vti_bin/shtml.exe/reservations.htm
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 04 Jan 2013 08:57:04 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) FrontPage/5.0.2.2635
Content-Length: 18680
Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1252
```

Your local system, presumably, does not. It looks like you can get them from [here](https://code.google.com/p/fp-ext-ubuntu/).

Personally, I'd rewrite the site to avoid them. They aren't a common tool for server side logic these days. (I don't remember seeing anyone else use this this century).

Comment: thanks for your valuable reply.Actually I did'nt developed this site.My task is to solve a payment problem.So that i download all the files form the server and setup it in my localhost.How can i solve this shtml.exe problem in my localhost

Comment: Install FrontPage Extensions as per the paragraph immediately following the HTTP response header data.